# Can I store extra pizza dough in fridge?

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, pizza, dough, refrigerator

I kneaded some pizza dough and it turned out that I have done this double the amount I wanted to. This is my first time. Can I store this dough in fridge? And for how many days?

Comment: A related post https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/86179/78955 says up to two weeks.  Mine is at 10 days.... I'll try and report.

Comment: Per Adam Ragusea, longe the dough is in freezer, the better it is. I have used 8 days old dough, worked well for me. I have gone to next level after posting this question 10 years ago :-)

Comment: I used my frozen pizza dough after about 3 weeks in the freezer.  I let it come up to almost room temperature and it came out fine.  A little different experience rolling it out, etc. but nothing urgent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can store it for about a day in the fridge. Let it warm up again before you cook it though.

Comment: it turns out that my first take on baking a pizza was 80% good, I kneaded dough for one pizza but it seems I can bake at least 3 pizzas :-) thanks for your help

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the colder the fridge, the longer you can keep the dough in the fridge. It will overrise after a day or two. Take it out of the fridge for an hour or two until it happily rises.

Pizza dough can also be frozen. I freeze mine immediately after finishing, and thaw it in the fridge for a day. Supposedly you can thaw it in the microwave.

Comment: only at the lowest power in the microwave.... if you raise the temp of the dough too high you will kill the yeast.

Answer (score 1):

Put it into the fridge in a zip loc bag or in tub and leave in the fridge until you would like to use it.

To freeze, coat in a light layer of oil and keep in a zip loc bag (freezer safe), remove the air from the bag and freeze for up to 3 months :)

Hope this helps :D

Happy cooking.