# How to store pizza dough in the fridge?

Tags: pizza

I’m making about 12 pizza doughs. Typically when I make a few, I store each one in a ziplock and try to reduce air. But in this case I was wondering if I can just get away with a full size baking sheet and store as many dough with enough space between. Then wrap in cling wrap to secure it from drying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this site](http://www.finecooking.com/recipe/make-ahead-pizza-dough)

> **Make Ahead Tips**
>
> The dough will keep in the refrigerator for up to 2 weeks. After 2
>   days, tightly cover the dough in its bowl with plastic wrap to keep
>   the surface of the dough from drying out. You can also freeze the
>   dough in well-wrapped 1/2-lb. balls for up to 3 weeks. Thaw overnight
>   in the refrigerator before using.

Comment: I always freeze mine in a ziplock bag, works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

When I make a batch of pizza dough, I ball the dough (typically 12-18 oz for the size pizza I make), and put on an oiled half sheet pan (or a 2 inch hotel pan). I am generous with the oil in the bottom of the pan and cover all sides of the dough ball when I put it into the pan. I usually have 6 balls in the pan.

Even if the dough touches, the oil should prevent the balls from turning into one huge slab of dough. I cover the dough with plastic wrap, but in the pizzeria I worked at, we just covered with oil.

I never take dough out of the refrigerator and stretch immediately. I take however many I need out, and let them warm slightly before I stretch out the pizza.